# How to reference the current year within a paper?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Whilst writing a paper about the use of digital technologies within education, it became apparent that it would be beneficial to reference the current year (in this case, 2016) to give the paragraph context, particularly with the rapid pace of change within this topic.

**What is the best manner to make this kind of reference in the APA style?**

Ideas:

> At the time of writing (2016), current computing trends...
>
> Currently (2016), computing trends...
>
> As of 2016, current computing trends...

Comment: I don't think it's normal to reference the current year. It's sort of implied that all statements in your paper are limited to the time of writing, unless stated otherwise. And it's rather trivial to find the submission date, if necessary. So, something like "At the time of writing, current computing trends..." sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable, the only reason I think contextually it would be helpful is that I'm building an argument around the need to refresh educational technology constantly to keep devices current and usable for students; and that more than 3 years have passed since the last round of government funding for such devices, therefore passing the costs onto schools - which I argue isn't sustainable. That said, I suppose the argument could still stand without a specific date mentioned.

Comment: I think "current" may be a bit redundant with 2016, and certainly will become wrong in the future. I would either say specifically 2016, or say current and let your publication date make clear when "current" refers to, or reference the specific years of the sources you might be citing "As of Paul's annual report in 2016, computing trends..." I'll keep this as a comment rather than an answer because I have no idea what the specific APA style would be for this question or if APA even has a guideline on this.

Comment: @BryanKrause Can you please turn this comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?